# Regex for matching below requirement

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create Regex for matching:

I have tried below regex but only first condition is working return DS_.
Anything else after DS_ will be fine but DS_TRUE should not match.

```
Regex = (re.findall('(return DS_)|(return Status)&(^!return DS_TRUE)', Line))

****Should Match**** 
Line = 'return DS_YES' 
Line = 'return DS_FALSE'
Line = 'return DS_EVER'
Line = 'return Status'
****Should not match****
Line = 'return DS_TRUE'
```

Comment: What are you doing? To check if a line is not equal to `return DS_TRUE` just split into lines/read file line by line and check `if line != 'return DS_TRUE'`.

Comment: `re.findall('(return DS_(?!TRUE).*|return Status)', Line)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern `(return DS_)|(return Status)&(^!return DS_TRUE)` contains 3 capturing groups.

The first group matches `return DS_`, the second group matches `return Status` followed by matching an ampersand.

The third group uses an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string followed by matching `!return DS_TRUE`.

You could use a negative lookahead after return to assert what is on the right is not DS_TRUE.

```
\breturn (?!DS_TRUE).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/prJrMQ/1)

If you want to match from the start of the string, you might also use an anchor `^` instead of a word boundary `\b`.

If you only want to match only if it starts with `DS_` and then all that follows or only Status, you could use:

```
\breturn (?!DS_TRUE)(?:DS_.*|Status)
```

- `\breturn[ ]` Word boundary, match return followed by a space (noted as `[ ]` for clarity only)
- `(?!DS_TRUE)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not DS_TRUE
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `DS_.*` Match DS_ followed by matching 0+ chars except a newline
  - `|` Or
  - `Status` Match Status
- `)` Close non capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/prJrMQ/2) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6GPCSZ)

Comment: It should match only above four not others. It is matching everything else then DS_TRUE. But it should match the return with starting DS_ or return Status.

Comment: @PRUTHVIBENPATEL In your question it states: `Anything else after DS_ will be fine but DS_TRUE should not match.`

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
import re

Line = """ 'return DS_YES' 
Line = 'return DS_FALSE'
Line = 'return DS_EVER'
Line = 'return Status'
Line = 'return DS_TRUE'
"""

r = re.findall('(return DS_(?!TRUE).*|return Status)', Line)
print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
["return DS_YES' ", "return DS_FALSE'", "return DS_EVER'", 'return Status']
```